# Ignore all warnings in a specific file using LLVM/Clang

Tags: xcode, clang, compiler-warnings

There are some files in my iOS project that have some warnings, and I want to ignore those warnings. I don't want to disable warnings in the entire project (know how to do that), just some specific files. So, is there a way to completely ignore all warnings from a specific file?

I'm using LLVM 3.0 and Clang on Xcode 4.2.

Comment: Are they YOUR sources, or someone else's in your project? If they're someone else's, the best approach might be to put them in a static library and link them in.

Comment: Answer given here is very elegant:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921884/xcode-4-how-to-suppress-all-warning-in-specific-source-file

Answer (score 76, accepted):

if you're just using clang, then you should use the pragma syntax for sources you maintain (assuming it is impossible to remove the warning by altering the program appropriately).

[here is the syntax:](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#diagnostics_pragmas)

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wmultichar"

char b = 'df'; // no warning.

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

if these are programs you cannot change and don't maintain, you should specify the warning(s) to disable for the file, rather than all. to disable all, you can add the per file argument `-w`. sources change, and some warnings do (or do not) apply with different build settings. clang's messages can tell you what flag equates to the generated warning.

To use Xcode to alter a file's build flags:

- select the target
- select the build phase
- locate the file to modify the arguments in the "Compile Sources" phase
- double click its "Compiler Flags" cell to edit

Answer (score 98):

I inherited a project that contained a lot of 320 code, and that code base threw several warnings and static analyzer errors at me that I had no interest in fixing since I will be removing that code from the project in the near future.

You can disable static analyzer warnings for a specific file by including the following compiler flag:

```
-Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-all-checks
```

You can combine this with -w to disable warnings for that file as well.  That has allowed me to push forward with new development while not having to be pestered with the 30 or so warnings generated by that code base.

Using the instructions from above:
To use Xcode to alter a file's build flags:

1. select the target
2. select the build phase
3. locate the file to modify the arguments in the "Compile Sources" phase
4. double click its "Compiler Flags" cell to edit
5. add "-w -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-all-checks" to suppress warnings and clang warnings

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a bunch for that compiler flag, just what I needed.

Comment: Newer versions of clang (i.e., 4.x in iOS6) appear to have made this option -Xclang -analyzer-disable-checker

Comment: The -Xanalyzer form still works in my newly installed XCode (version 4.5.1, IOS6). The other form does not work.

Comment: This worked in XCode 4.5.2 to disable 'The right operand of '+' is a garbage value' in 3rd-party source (RegexKitLite.m) ([Bug Report](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3601139&group_id=204582&atid=990188)).  The accepted answer did not.  It would be helpful to update this answer with the difference between what `-Xanalyzer`, `-w`, and `-analyzer-disable-checker` do.

Answer (score 25):

With the help of justin's answer, this is how you do

#### 1. Locate the name of the warning.

In my case its `conversion`

[image]

#### 2. Add a per file compiler flag build phases

Use the filter to find the name of the file in compile sources, type `-Wno-[error name]` e.g. `-Wno-conversion`

[image]

Comment: Hallelujah! I searched high and low for this. The syntax of the -W option doesn't appear to be documented anywhere!

Answer (score 3):

You can select specific target -> Build settings, search for Inhibit All Warnings and set to YES. This will disable warnings on this target.
This can be useful if you use some code like JSONKit with cocoapods, and you don't want to see how compiler cries about warnings :)