# Xcode disable `Value stored to '...' during its initialization is never read` analyzer warnings

Tags: xcode, clang, clang-static-analyzer

I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897429/ignore-all-warnings-in-a-specific-file-using-llvm-clang/8087544#8087544) that I can disable analyzer warnings by adding `-Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-all-checks` to the compiler flags, however I do not wish to disable every warning, just this one warning. I understand that I should be able to figure out the specific warning from the output, but I cannot seem to find it:

> /Users/.../file.m:1543:17: warning: Value stored to '...' during its initialization is never read
>           CGFloat height = initialValue;

Obviously, I could resolve this by removing the initialValue, but I'm wondering if I could instead disable the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `#pragma` directive to silence a specific warning. Have a look at this answer:

[Is there a way to suppress warnings in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7992423/454362)

There are other solutions on the same page that also might work for you.